# Functional equation of the $L$-function of a motive

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose $M$ is a pure motive over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $L(M,s)$ be its $L$-function obtained as product of local $L$-factors at non-archimedean places, while let $L_\infty(M,s)$ be the product of $L$-factors at archimedean places. The total $L$-function is
\begin{equation}
\Lambda(M,s)=L(M,s)L_\infty(M,s)
\end{equation}
The total $L$-function is conjectured to satisfy a functional equation
\begin{equation}
\Lambda(M,s)=\epsilon(M,s)\Lambda(M^\vee,1-s)
\end{equation}
where $M^\vee$ is the dual of $M$. Could anyone discuss some intuitions (examples) why this should be true, e.g., why we need to take the dual of $M$? Why it is $1-s$ on the right hand side instead of say $n-s, n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ in general?

Comment: Someone else can say something in more detail, but $s \mapsto 1 - s$ is due to a particular normalization of the $L$-function. The other common normalization for the functional equation has $k - s$ on right side where $k$ is the weight of $M$. I personally think of the functional equation as an analytic duality that matches up with algebraic duality of $M$ and $M^\vee$.

Comment: I don't know anything about motives, but it might be helpful to compare this with Galois representations: if $\rho : Gal(\bar{K}/K) \rightarrow GL_d(\mathbb{C})$ is a representation of the absolute galois group of the number field $K$ then the complete Artin L-function $\Lambda(\rho,s)$ satisfies the functional equation $\Lambda(\rho,s) = \epsilon(\rho,s) \Lambda(\rho^*,s)$ where $\rho^*$ is the contragradient representation of $\rho$. 
The $1-s$ factor shows that there is symmetry around the line $\Re(s) = 1/2$, relevant to Riemann hypothesis and Weil conjectures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some clarification is needed in the definition of your motif $M$ and its $L$-function. For two number fields, $F$ and $E$, recall that the (still  conjectural) "mixed motives" defined over $F$, with coefficients in $E$, are supposed to be the objects $M$ of a certain category $\mathcal M\mathcal M_F (E)$ with a "unit object" $1_{F,E}$. The dual motif $M^*$ of $M$ should be $Hom (M,1_{F,E})$, and for all $i\in \mathbf N$, the "motivic cohomology groups" should be defined as $H_{\mathcal M\mathcal M}^i (F,M):= Ext_{\mathcal M\mathcal M}^i (1_{F,E},M)$. In practice, one works only with a system of étale, Betti and de Rham "realizations" (the sanksrit word "avatars" would be more suggestive) of the hypothetical motif $M$, together with comparison isomorphisms. For $E=\mathbf Q$, an important particular example is the Tate motif $\mathbf Q(m), m\in \mathbf Z$, which is a pure motif over $F$ of weight $-2m$, whose étale avatars $M_{\mathcal L}$, for all places $\mathcal L$ of $E$ above prime numbers $\mathcal l$, are the Tate twists $\mathbf Q_\mathcal l (m)$; whose Betti avatars, for all the archimedean places of $F$, are $(2\pi i)^m \mathbf Q$; whose de Rham avatar is $F$ equipped with a certain filtration. Here note that for $m\in \mathbf N,\mathbf Q(m)= \mathbf Q(1)^{\otimes m}$, and the dual of $\mathbf Q(m)$ is $\mathbf Q(-m)$. The $L$-function $L(\mathbf Q(m),s)$ is the shifted Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_F (s+m)$. To avoid sinking an already overloaded boat, I refer to [Pu] below for more details.

With the example of the Tate motives in mind, Deligne (1979) has given an axiomatic definition of the category of "Deligne 1-motives" and of the attached $L$-functions, and has conjectured the functional equation they should satisfy (as written in your post). When $E=\mathbf Q$, no wonder then that the dual motif enters the game, as well as the change of variables $s \to 1-s$. Besides,if you look at Tate's approach to Hecke- zeta functions using Fourier analysis in number fields (his  1950 thesis), the functional equation is written $\zeta(f,c)=\zeta(\hat f, \hat c)$, where $\hat f\in L^1(\hat G)$ is the Fourier transform of $f\in L^1( G)$ (see his main theorem 4.4.1 for the precise statements). When going back to the Dedekind functions $\zeta(s,\chi)$, the passage between the two "dual" expressions above corresponds to $(s, \chi) \to(1-s, \chi^{-1})$ .

[Pu] "The Bloch-Kato conjecture for the Riemann zeta function", Proceedings of the Pune 2012 Conference, London Math. Soc. LNS 418 (2015). See in particular chapters 1 and 9.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If the coefficient field $E$ is not $\mathbb{Q}$, how to define the realisations? For example, for two different motives $M_1$ and $M_2$, the morphisms between them form an $E$ vector space. If there is a realisation into a category such that the morphisms between two objects form a $K$ vector space, then does this mean $E$ must be embedded in to $F$?

Comment: It's a bit complicated because  1) The category of mixed motives with coefficients in E  is not yet fully known     2) To study motivic L-functions, it is not necessary to know realizations (avatars) of the motif itself, only of its motivic cohomology, which can be defined in terms of Chow groups (this was achieved by Voevoedsky)  3)  In an even more pedestrian way, one can use a "hand made" category MS_F (E) of "motivic structures for the working mathematician", but still too elaborate for me to type here. See e.g. [Pu], §9.3.2.